# mySQL - subtract values that exist in another table

Tags: mysql

I apologize if this is a duplicate, however, I cannot find the answer I need.

Consider my data:

**Table - report_detail**

```
report_id   |category    |sub_category   |report name
-------------------------------------------------------
1           |1           |1              |Donkey Report
2           |2           |2              |Grandma Report
3           |1           |1              |Poop Report
```

**Table - report_subscriptions**

```
user_id     |report_id
--------------------------
1           |1            
2           |2            
1           |2
```

My question is, how do I select all of the report_id's from the report_detail table that are not subscribed to user_id = 1 in report_subscriptions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you fairly close

```
select * from Report_detail RD
where RD.report_id not in (select disctinct RS.report_id from report_subscriptions RS)
```

Comment: I think you need a where condition in your subselect.

Comment: Adding the where clause made it work.  Thank you! ----------   SELECT r.report_id, r.report_name FROM research_report_detail AS r
WHERE r.report_id NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT s.report_id FROM research_report_subscriptions AS s WHERE s.user_id = 1)

Comment: I'm sorry... I totally missed that condition that you set... Glad it, at least, led you to your solution. :D

Answer (score 0):

Tested at SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7e3a/1/0

```
select rd.report_id 
from   report_detail rd
where  not exists (
           select 1 
           from   report_subscriptions rs 
           where  rs.user_id = 1 
                  and rs.report_id = rd.report_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the report id's there is no reason to get the report_detail table involved at all.
Simply do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT report_id FROM report_subscriptions WHERE user_id <> 1
```

If you actually need to get data from the report_details table using this constraint, simply do

```
SELECT * FROM report_detail
WHERE report_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT report_id FROM report_subscriptions WHERE user_id <> 1)
```